# Persisting URL params on form_set_error

Tags: forms

## Scenario

I have a page which looks like 
  http://notfound.stackexchange.com?a=1&b=2

After validation, i use **form_set_error** to display a drupal error message on the same page(url)
but end up without the url params 
  http://notfound.stackexchange.com

## Question

- Is there a way to preserve/persist the url params on **form_set_error** ?
- Is using **drupal_goto** the correct way (since i can send the url params again) to redirect to the same page ?
- **hidden form elements** to store the params for use on different pages in the process flow, but as a last resort if there is no other way ?

Comment: Please let me see your `drupal_goto` code.

Comment: @NikhilM : `drupal_goto($url, array('query' => array('a' = $value1, 'b' = $value2)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;`

This works like a charm since the form is not rebuilt or reloaded.
Below link contains more info
https://drupal.org/node/1850410